# Changing colors on dimple.js scatter plot

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

How can I change the color of the circles on a scatter plot based on one of the fields that I'm not using on neither of the axes?

Example, this code:

```
var myChart3 = new dimple.chart(svg3, data);
myChart3.addMeasureAxis("x", "salary"); 
myChart3.addMeasureAxis("y", "bonus");                  
var mySeries = myChart3.addSeries(["Index","a"], dimple.plot.scatter);
myChart3.draw();
```

produces this graph:
[image]

but I also would like to color the bubbles based on a third field called "department"

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of `addSeries` determines colours.  In the case of an array the last element is used, so you just need to do:

```
var mySeries = myChart3.addSeries(["Index","a","department"], dimple.plot.scatter);
```

Comment: perfect, thanks very much. Two follow up questions: 1) can I choose the colors instead of the default ones? 2) See the "a" in there? that's a dummy field I added to avoid the data begin aggregated at the "index" level. It works fine but it is a hack. Is there a "correct" way to avoid aggregation?

Comment: The "a" field shouldn't be required.  The behaviour you are describing is required if you are drawing a line plot with 2 measure axes.  The scatter plot will disaggregate based on all distinct values in the first parameter of addSeries.  In your case "Index" and "Department".  The "a" string won't do anything.

Comment: You can pick different arbitrarily assigned colours using chart.defaultColors (https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#defaultColors) or you can assign particular colours using chart.assignColor (https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#assignColor)